# Prevent evaluation of the sum of two vectors while still displaying the vectors in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I am trying to achieve the following in Maxima (to be precise: I am using STACK for Moodle which uses Maxima):

```
v1:matrix([1],[0],[0]);
v2:matrix([0],[1],[0]);
v3:r*v1+s*v2;
```

I now want the summation in v3 not to be evaluated while still the previously defined vectors v1 and v2 to be substituted in, that is for my output I want to have something like

```
   [1]   [0]
 r*[0]+s*[1]
   [0]   [0]
```

While I can suppress the evaluation of the sum using

```
v3:'(r*v1+s*v2)
```

this results in

```
rv1+sv2
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

If it helps:

```
 [r] [0]
 [0]+[s]
 [0] [0]
```

would also be ok for the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v1:matrix([1],[0],[0]);
v2:matrix([0],[1],[0]);
simp:false$
v3:r*v1+s*v2;
simp:true$
```

This will do fine in Maxima, in STACK it seems that for some reason the

```
simp:true$
```

can't be used because it will also simplify everything again. So I just moved everything I do not want to be simplified to the bottom of the code. Also the notation in stack would be

```
simp:false;
```

since $ can't be used.

Comment: Disabling simplification entirely via `simp: false` affects many other operations -- it's better to just the flags which are necessary to get the result. See my answer for more about that.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix operations are governed by a number of flags -- `doallmxops` and so on. `?? domx`, `?? dosc`, and `?? dot` will find most or all of them.

In this case, what you what to do is to suppress adding matrices together -- for this purpose `doallmxops: false` and `domxmxops: false` has the desired effect.

It's much better to set just these flags to get the result, rather than entirely disabling simplification, which will have a very broad and probably unexpected effect.